# CI display for ggplot2

Tags: r, matrix, ggplot2

I have a matrix that looks like

```
 m =    structure(c(323.779052983988, 468.515895704753, 587.268448071498, 
701.348128517059, 779.979804648318, 727.214175106036, 907.318055915511, 
1115.76665653904, 256.756620668571, 402.701329692437, 487.179245291945, 
490.318053207526, 654.076130682292, 637.123436099074, 722.662552444773, 
792.505947658499, 403.652330928532, 577.534367257774, 900.565634583409, 
920.152416244856, 2357.72405145892, 3587.16328098826, 1452.70178195117, 
1579.28418044468, 338.358847483685, 454.199083058843, 599.97279688233, 
700.985565850218, 741.316909631413, 801.287026382171, 922.197411647728, 
1114.06641511944, 291.406778366111, 395.588263809182, 605.249603657004, 
499.747863299406, 535.230373829629, 542.056360622003, 796.821508497618, 
765.755975092841, 385.004883847313, 658.784861034504, 822.223611208372, 
1145.62924659969, 874.330710055459, 2138.50154766236, 1622.81483333837, 
5233.38890249983, 326.628586231411, 475.233191752907, 584.49028480417, 
700.341240251852, 786.302433055766, 900.413365602976, 964.629943008088, 
1028.82949413297, 338.629636961477, 488.195412653447, 587.800574630787, 
716.597816045267, 822.268333195828, 998.509804262574, 1037.41705762635, 
1070.88757066892, 365.518529559524, 545.02881088877, 675.193759918472, 
850.711841186985, 1006.39383294974, 1155.64170488707, 1318.06948607024, 
1382.22753306512, 326.238411688287, 468.96417383265, 579.601628485875, 
687.695555889267, 781.084920045155, 873.426833221962, 951.816393171732, 
1040.03875034591, 335.355219968458, 486.147238845314, 623.244412005171, 
748.505818444964, 860.86919935457, 983.642351192889, 1139.59065966632, 
1231.14044698001, 350.834428083403, 510.783163477734, 661.443754597131, 
809.775151175334, 937.8698594887, 1095.74073622628, 1275.45665833418, 
1409.44183362004), .Dim = c(8L, 12L))
```

So cols 1,4,7 and 10 are the height of the bars. I want to do a grouped bar plot in ggplot2 so I do

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

m[,c(1,4,7,10)]->m1
as.data.frame(m1)->m1
rownames(m1)<-c("t2","t3","t4","t5","t6","t7","t8","t9")
colnames(m1)<-c("a1","a2","a3","a4")
t(m1)->m1
melt(m1)->m1


ggplot(m1, aes(factor(Var2), value, fill = Var1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

Now I want to use cols 2,3;5,6;8,9 and 11,12 to draw error bars on the plot. So for the values in col 1, col 2 provides the lower CI and col 3 provides the upper CI (in absolute terms). This is then also for Cols 5 and 6 - that do that for col 4....
I found this here http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_errorbar.html

but it only shows how to draw symmetric error bars - can somebody show me how to add error bars based on cols 2,3 .... to the grouped bar plot?

Comment: nobody with an idea?

Comment: Have a look at the last example at `?geom_errorbar`

Comment: @Sandy Muspratt sorry - but it says somethign about drawing lines - If we want to draw lines, we need to manually set the
# groups which define the lines - here the groups in the
# original dataframe - so not sure I do understand. Is it feasible that you provide some sort of example where you show how to obtain what I have in mind, please?

Comment: I don't think you are looking at the last example. It draws geom_bar and geom_errorbar.

Comment: sorry but not on this page http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_errorbar.html

Comment: @sandy Muspratt could you please help out? That would be really great - think i provided the data and so just need to draw the bars

Comment: One more try. In the R console, type `?geom_errorbar`.

Comment: the examples are the same - can you maybe just write what you mean? That would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You example was not reproducible, so here's a slightly modified version of the example from `?geom_errorbar`.  Note that df contains variables `upper` and `lower` which are the upper and lower limits of the errorbars.

```
df <- data.frame(
  trt = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2)),
  resp = c(1, 5, 3, 4),
  group = factor(c(1, 2, 1, 2)),
  upper = c(1.1, 5.3, 3.3, 4.2),
  lower = c(0.8, 4.6, 2.4, 3.6)
)

dodge <- position_dodge(width=0.9)

ggplot(df, aes(trt, resp, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(position = dodge, stat = "identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), position = dodge, width = 0.25)
```

Using your data.

```
# Values for the bar plots
m[,c(1,4,7,10)]->m1
as.data.frame(m1)->m1
rownames(m1)<-c("t2","t3","t4","t5","t6","t7","t8","t9")
colnames(m1)<-c("a1","a2","a3","a4")
t(m1)->m1
melt(m1)->m1

# Upper and lower limits for the error bars
error = m[,c(2,3,5,6,8,9,11,12)]
error = data.frame(error)

rownames(error)<-c("t2","t3","t4","t5","t6","t7","t8","t9")
colnames(error) = rep(c("a1","a2","a3","a4"), each = 2)

error = t(error)
error = melt(error)

error = cbind(error[seq(1, dim(error)[1], 2), ], error[seq(2, dim(error)[1], 2), 3])
names(error)[3:4] = c("lower", "upper")

# Combine the error bars and bar plot data frames
m1 = cbind(m1, error[, 3:4])

# Construct the plot
dodge <- position_dodge(width=0.9)

ggplot(m1, aes(factor(Var2), value, fill = Var1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = dodge) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), position = dodge, width = 0.25) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

Comment: hi - could you tell me, why the example was not repro? I can copy paste and it works???

Comment: So I've edited your code so that the code runs. But  also, I do not know how to manipulate the `m` data frame to get a data frame of upper and lower limits for the error bars.

Comment: well - that is the problem I am currently facing as well. The u and l values are in col 2,3;5,6;8,9 and 11,12 for col 1,4,7,10....

Comment: @kutyw I've added a graph using your data. Is this what you were expecting?